# MYSQL Insert with Select and if select returns more than 1 value insert both

Tags: php, mysql

Quite simple but I dont get it. Any Solution?

For example: if there is 2 times the name peter. But you should insert both.

```
insert into table1 (id,firstname,zip) values ('%s',(select nametable from table2 where name='peter'),'1234');
```

I hope its understandable

Edit: you get the id.. i just changed it...

I want to insert something where I have to select from another table. But the problem is sometimes i get more than 1 result. If there is more than 1 result I want to insert all results.

Comment: No, is not understable.

Comment: Where is ID coming from? 
You could drop the "values" and do "insert into table 1 (select ... from table2)" but I'm not sure what you want in the ID field.

Comment: The send SELECT statement is redundant . because you are asking for name by referencing name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into table1 (id, name, zip) ...
```

And what would you like to insert into it?

```
... select id, nametable, '1234'
from table2 
where name='peter'
```

Now you connect those 2 pieces and it should work

Comment: Its not about connecting them. When the Select results more than 1 row it doesnt insert anything. And I want it to insert anything. Thats my problem.

Comment: My query is slightly different than yours. You might want to have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: okay I see and how do i do it if i need to do another select go get ID?

Comment: The second part (the select part of the insert statement) is like any other query. You can add filters with `and` and/or `or`, you can add `UNION`, ... Go through the w3schools to get a basic idea how sql statements work

Comment: Ok I think i get what you mean. Thanks for the help.